# how to handle popup ok message accept with selenium alert

Tags: python, selenium

After registration a pop up alert with ok message 'successfully registered' appeared. I tried handle that with below code.

```
alert1= driver.switch_to_alert()
alert1.accept()
```

it is throwing below error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no alert open
```

Is there any way to handle the popup ok message.

Comment: Are you sure that it is an alert? Can you right-click on this popup?

Comment: No, I cannot . I have only two options in the popup .

Comment: 1. ok 
2. close - x mark to click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is throwing the "no alert present" exception, it might not be a windows alert but a dialog box which you can handle with selenium.

Please try the following:

When that webpage is open with the pop up, right click on it and click inspect. If you can find the CSS Selector of it, you can easily click on the "ok" button through selenium.

Comment: Thanks. I found the CSS. I wrote selenium cold like this

Comment: <input type="button" class="redBtn" onclick="$.colorbox.close()" value="OK">

saveokalert=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="redBtn"]')

for okalert in saveokalert:
    print "inside ok"
    if okalert.value_of_css_property("value")=="OK":
        print "ok alert inside"
        okalert.click()

Comment: Can you try: driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("button.redBtn)).click();

Comment: i tried . below exception is observed .

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".redBtn[value='OK']").click()

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

Comment: it worked with below code. 
driver.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).click();", element)

Answer (score 0):

You can use wait before your code  :-

```
 WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                                   'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' +
                                   'confirmation popup to appear.')

    alert = browser.switch_to.alert()
    alert.accept()
```